# Can I block the autoplay GIFs on "Giphy", "Tenor GIF Keyboard", etc, on Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, gif, animated-gif

Facebook Messenger allows people to link in with sites like Tenor and Giphy to add GIFs to a conversation that play on a loop without user input. Facebook have shown no interest in allowing users to hide these images or forcing the images themselves to conform to the user's "autoplay videos" setting, so is there any way to block them via a uBlock Origin filter that will not affect anything else on Facebook?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use the following uBlock Origin filter:

```
https://*.fb*.*/v/t*.*/*.gif
```

This will stop the images from loading, displaying instead a grey square.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add this filter:

```
https://*.fb*.*/v/t*.*/*.mp4
```

Many "gifs" on Facebook are actually mp4 files, apparently. It didn't work until I did this.